# Undefined symbols Xcode error when using Firebase with Google Toolbox for Mac

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-toolbox-for-mac

I have an iOS project which uses Firebase and Google Toolbox for Mac, which are added via Pods. My Podfile is as follows:

```
target 'MyApp' do
    pod 'GoogleToolboxForMac', '~> 2.1'
    pod 'GTMSessionFetcher', '~> 1.1'

    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
end
```

When I build the project in Xcode I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMLogger", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseMessaging(GIPReachability_ae5504e4a6a28a1d8997c6f38e8bff8b.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can anyone advise? Judging from other similar questions I may need import a framework in `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`. I've added `UserNotifications.framework` for Firebase Messaging, but not sure what else I'd need...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to add [another Cocoapod](https://cocoapods.org/?q=gtm-logger) to your `Podfile`:

```
target 'MyApp' do
    pod 'GoogleToolboxForMac', '~> 2.1'
    pod 'GTMSessionFetcher', '~> 1.1' # version 1.1 & newer up to - but not including - 2.0
    pod 'gtm-logger', '>= 0.0.5' # version 0.0.5 or newer

    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
end
```

and then run `pod update`